# How to match substring, do regular match of string in shell?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I'm checking whether these three SUBSTRING is in STRING.

**STRING:**

```
active
mac address ec:f4:bb:e1:0c:18
Link Up - speed 10000 Mbps - full-duplex
LACP actor_state ACTIVE AGGREGATION SYNC COLLECTING DISTRIBUTING
```

**SUBSTRING:**

1. active
2. ACTIVE
3. DISTRIBUTING

I try to use these in my shell script:

```
dpdkb2_slave0_res=$(/usr/local/bin/ovs-appctl dpdk/bond-show dpdkb2 | sed -n '5,8p')
dpdkb2_slave1_res=$(/usr/local/bin/ovs-appctl dpdk/bond-show dpdkb2 | sed -n '14,17p')

s0_active=$(expr index $dpdkb2_slave0_res 'active')
if [[ -n "$dpdkb2_slave0_res" && $s0_active -ne 0 ]]  ; then
    ok_output "dpdkb2 status is ok:"
    ok_output "$dpdkb2_res"
```

but in line4, report error: **expr: syntax error**.

But it's OK when I run `expr index $dpdkb2_slave0_res 'active'` command in shell.

1. How to fix this?
2. How to do string location, search, replace? Which one is most effective, `expr` or `{string##}` or `awk` or `sed`?

I have to say it's hard work to use shell, there is no way to process string in shell, shell have to process strings by tools like awk, sed, grep. I don't know why.

Last question:

3. how to match three worlds together? I want to use `active*ACTIVE*DISTRIBUTING`, but both `awk` and `sed` report error.

Comment: if it's only *checking whether these three SUBSTRING is in STRING* (as you wrote) - it can be achieved with one line approach

Comment: Regarding #3 - `sed -r '/(active|ACTIVE|DISTRIBUTING)/'`

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve all you want to do by using `awk`,

```
$ awk 'match($0,/ACTIVE/){printf "%d ",RSTART} sub("ACTIVE","xxx",$0)' file
18 LACP actor_state xxx AGGREGATION SYNC COLLECTING DISTRIBUTING

$ awk 'match($0,/active/){printf "%d ",RSTART} sub("active","yyy",$0)' file
1 yyy

$ awk 'match($0,/DISTRIBUTING/){printf "%d ",RSTART} sub("DISTRIBUTING","zzz",$0)' file
53 LACP actor_state ACTIVE AGGREGATION SYNC COLLECTING zzz
```

Brief explaination,

- First output of each command would be the start point of the substring, i.e., ACTIVE, active, and DISTRIBUTING.
- Second output of the command would be the result substitute by specific patteren, i.e., xxx, yyy, and zzz. And you may change to the desired substitutions as your request.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear for which shell you are searching a solution, but from your examples, I guess you don't need something which is guaranteed to be POSIX compliant.

Since you don't seem to need the actual position of the substring, but only the whether or not the substring appears, the following should work at least in Zsh and bash:

```
if [[ $dpdkb2_slave0_res == *active* ]]
then
  ok_output "dpdkb2 status is ok:"
  ...
fi
```

It's not clear to me what you mean by *using the words together*, but maybe you mean something like

```
if [[ $dpdkb2_slave0_res == *ACTIVE*DISTRIBUTING* ]]
```